# Как правильно записать формулу в с++

Tags: c++

я понимаю, что ошибка в части с логарифмом. Вопрос: как правильно в этой формуле записать логарифм и индексы, + объясните пожалуйста почему так, будет круто, если с ссылкой на источник.

[image: пример, который нужно решить]

```html
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
 double S;
 cout << "Enter S=";
 cin >> S;

 double U;
 cout << "Enter U=";
 cin >> U;

 double T = log(2*U+1)*(3*U+0.12) - 10 / (S + 23);

 cout << "T:" << T << endl;
 system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`log(x)` возвращает натуральный логарифм от `x`. Чтобы посчитать логарифм по другому основанию, можно воспользоваться формулой:

```
 logb(x) = loga(x) / loga(b)
```

В результате получится:

```
 double T = log(3*U+0.12) / log(2.0*U+1) - 10 / (S + 23);
```

Answer (score 2):

В си основание логарифма только натуральное **e**. Нужно перенести на другое основание:

`log a (b) = ln(b) / ln(a)`

```
log(3.0*U+0.12) / log (2.0*U+1.0)
```